# View DHCP Server Leases

Tags: dhcp-server

How can I view the dhcpd.leases without having to SSH into the box and view using vi/nano etc.

I used to have webadmin set up on another box but that was when I used the GUI to configure dhcp.

Now I have configured it myself through the terminal and don't want to use webadmin. and viewing the dhcpd.leases file in the web browser was very nifty!

Any software/scripts that automatically export the leases file into a web page that i can view using apache on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a web server installed on the same machine, you could just use a symlink to put it into a directory served by the web server.

If you have Apache configured to use `/var/www/htdocs`, you could use something like this:

```
ln -s /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases /var/www/htdocs/leases.txt
```

(Might need path adjustments depending on your system).

If the access rights are correct, you could read the file with `http://hostname/leases.txt` afterwards.

If would restrict this to the local network, though.

Comment: Works a treat. should suffice for what I need. Thank you very much sir!